# Where should someone start with WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

If I don't know anything about video/audio streaming or the networking part (STUN/TURN/ICE), where should I start? Are there any libraries/frameworks that make the development easier? The WebRTC website doesn't have anything useful

Comment: Did you try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API)?

Comment: Yes, but it's just a list of APIs, I don't know how to use such amount of complex information, I need a tutorial that won't assume that I know something about webrtc or that I have a server.

Answer (score 1):

I voted your question back up because WebRTC is so complex that it's really not unreasonable.  The only instance where it's simple is if you stick to peer-to-peer connections (and even those still require a signaling server).  I'd break it up into these sections (in no particular order, because you'll need to know all of it!):

- Browse jib's link to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) to get a general idea of the Javascript side of things.   Then head over to the [OpenWebRTC Demo](https://demo.openwebrtc.org/) page and browse the Javascript console and source to see how the handshake and data exchanges work.
- Read up on [SDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2327) files.  These files describe the video the peers expect and can send and this format is nasty.  The ordering and format of the standard are unclear.  A lot of things can go wrong if you have a bad SDP file.  [webrtchacks.com](https://webrtchacks.com) has a decent starter tutorial on it.  [webrtchacks.com](https://webrtchacks.com) is also just a good read in general for familiarizing yourself with WebRTC.
- Read up on [STUN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389)/[TURN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766)/[ICE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245).  You'll probably have to know something about these protocols to diagnose connection failures.
- Read up briefly on SRTP and RTP if you don't already know them.
- Of course you'll need to know about h264 or vp8.
- If you have Chrome, their chrome://webrtc-internals link is useful for following where in the handshake you're at.

In response to your comment, even for a peer to peer session, an intermediary, "signaling" server is needed.  The [OpenWebRTC Demo](https://demo.openwebrtc.org/) page is an example of one of these signaling servers.  The two peers initially know nothing about each other.  Using the signaling server, they exchange offers and answers about what media they can send and receive, and what ICE/STUN/TURN settings should be used to establish connectivity to each other.  This "signaling" stage is where the "hole punching" you mention is done.

This [MDN Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling) does a pretty good job of describing signaling.  The RTCPeerConnection object is a pretty high level object that kinda represents the whole shebang.  As you can see from its API, it has stream information as well as signaling information.

Comment: Actually I don't think there's need for my own STUN (it seems there are some public ones like the one from Google) and TURN (someone mentioned that it's needed for around 15% - 20% of time), peer to peer  connections are what I'm interested in, but MDN doesn't really help, [for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/RTCPeerConnection) what exactly is RTCPeerConnection?What does it connect to (server or peer)?If it's another peer then how does it connect to it (isn't hole punching required for this?)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

- [WebRTC.org](https://webrtc.org/start/)
- [html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)
- [example code](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/)

Comment: Official webrtc page doesn't have any documentation or tutorials, I know about html5rocks and it's too difficult to follow and many things are either not explained well enough or are left to us (like server side and some unexplained variables), I don't need sample code, I need a beginner friendly tutorial (that will cover even the server side).